# Getting each integer in an int as a seperate int

Tags: java, integer

I'm curious as to how to efficiently get an integer for each int inside of an integer, for example:

```
private int example = 83491;
```

Would return the following numbers

8, 3, 4, 9, 1.

The current method I have is to convert them into a string, then stuff them into a char array, then convert them back into numbers whenever I want to use them, this is rediculously inefficient and there has to be another way.

I was thinking about how you could use

```
example % 10
```

and it would equal 1, but I couldn't really figure out if there was a way to change that "Magic Number" to get other placements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 83491;

        if (num < 0)
            num = -num;
        List<Integer> digits = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        while (num > 0) {
            digits.add(0, num % 10);
            num = num / 10;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits.toArray()));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[8, 3, 4, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you are right. you can do with %. Try like

```
int number=83491; 
LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
while (number > 0) {
    stack.push( number % 10 );
    number = number / 10;
}

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(stack.pop()+",);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
int num=83491;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(String.valueOf(num).toCharArray()));
```